# Breaker with alarm

Tags: circuit-breaker, security, normally-open

I am thinking about a theft alarm for an HVAC condenser. The condenser is installed outside and subject to burglary.   I think a viable approach is detecting when it is detached from power.

The HVAC has 5 connectors (2 for power, and 3 controller which communicates with the panel inside the building. In power connection, there is current if HVAC is on, but the controller has current (low power) all the time. I am thinking about if the control part is detached from the power source I can have the alarm inside the building.

I did a little search. I found power outage alarm solutions but they can be used for my goal since they are installed in parallel with the HVAC. Then I thought maybe there is a circuit breaker with alarm. While it seems there is such product I was not able to find any on online stores.

Here are my questions:

1. Do you have any suggestion on how I can have a safe alarm with minimal modifications?
2. Do you know any circuit breaker with alarm? (Please provide a link.)

Comment: Sorry, recommendations for specific products are off-topic for this site.

Comment: A security (alarm) professional would likely know a good solution.  If you have the ability to run two (AC power) wires from the condenser, use those to power a NC relay inside the building.  To those relay contacts, connect an alarm to the NC contact.  When the wire is cut, the relay closes, and the alarm sounds.

Answer (score 0):

You're working that problem from the wrong direction.

The unit doesn't draw any power when it's not cycled on, so there's nothing you could monitor on the AC voltage side that would distinguish between "cycled off" and "gone altogether".

However... A/C units typically have 24V controls going to them.  Normally it's simply a "the contactor coil".  A 24VAC transformer supplies R and C.  C and Y go to the air conditioning unit 24V contactor.  When the thermostat "calls for cool", it shorts R and Y, completing the circuit and the A/C unit starts with a massive motor surge and runs til the thermostat breaks R and Y.

Nowadays newer A/C units try to do better than that. So the A/C unit might also get the R wire to power its onboard smarts.

Regardless, the contactor coil has a resistance that is not zero and is not infinity.  And, it's in the 24V low-voltage domain, which means, you can "mess with it" without the risks and certification issues involved with AC mains.

You can also just change that control bundle out to a 4-wire or 5-wire cable, and put a resistor or capacitor of your choice between AA and C, or between AA and BB.  (to make up new wire designations not now used for HVAC).  The value of a resistor instead of a short/shunt is you will positively detect tampering.